# How do I use NMAKE on the command line?

Tags: nmake

I have Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 redistributable installed on my PC, but when I try to use the NMAKE command in the cmd it says:

> 'nmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

I went to the Visual Studio 8 folder, and I couldn't find `nmake.exe` or `vcvars32.bat`.

What should I do?

Comment: I don't think that the "redistributable" components contain `nmake`.

Comment: where can i get the nmake

Comment: Exactly what version of VS2012 are you using (Express, Professional, Ultimate)? "visual c++ 2012 redistributable" doesn't mean much, and the "visual studio 8" folder isn't for VS2012.

Comment: microsoft visual c++ 2012 redistributable (x86) 11.0.51106.1

Answer (score 5):

"Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 redistributable" just contains runtime libraries needed by applications developed with Visual C++ 2012. No development tools are included.

To obtain "nmake" you either have to buy "Visual Studio" or download the Windows SDK from Microsoft. When installing the SDK you'll find "nmake" in folder "\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio xx.x\VC\bin" (xx.x depending on SDK Version).

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio installs a couple of command-shell links under Start|Programs|Microsoft Visual Studio xx.

Comment: then how can i get the nmake??

Comment: @caesar: Type `nmake` into one of these shells.